# Fazer download de todos arquivos de uma pasta no FTP?

Tags: c#, winforms

Bom dia,

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que faz troca de arquivos .txt via FTP. Preciso fazer o download de todos os arquivos que estiverem em uma determinada pasta.

Hoje consigo fazer o download de um arquivo por vez, no caso eu passo as credenciais de conexão, nome da pasta e o nome do arquivo, mas dessa forma não está atendendo a minha necessidade.

O código abaixo está funcionando para um único download.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que eu preciso ajustar nesse código abaixo ? Se isso é possível para atender minha necessidade.

Obrigado

```
    public static void StartDownloads(out string pstrMsg, out bool pbooRetorno, string pstrUrl, string pstrLocal, string pstrUsuario, string pstrSenha)
    {
        pstrMsg = string.Empty;
        pbooRetorno = false;

        try
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pstrUrl);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            // Credenciais utilizadas para conectar no servidor FTP
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(pstrUsuario, pstrSenha);

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    // Cria o arquivo no local especificado
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pstrLocal))
                    {
                        string strLinhaArquivo = reader.ReadLine();

                        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strLinhaArquivo))
                        {
                            // Gravar as informações no arquivo
                            writer.Write(strLinhaArquivo);

                            // Verifica se o arquivo extraido contém linha
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((strLinhaArquivo = reader.ReadLine())))
                            {
                                // Inseri uma nova linha no arquivo
                                writer.WriteLine();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Uri uri = new Uri(pstrUrl);

            // Método deleta o arquivo assim que o download acaba
            DeleteFileOnServer(uri, pstrUsuario, pstrSenha); // request);

            pbooRetorno = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pstrMsg = string.Format("Erro:\nMétodo 'StartDownloads'\nDetalhes: {0}", ex.Message);

            pbooRetorno = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, eu já utilizei o código abaixo:

```
public void BaixarTodosArquivosDirFTP(string urlFTP, string usuario, string senha, string dirLocal)
{
    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlFTP);
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());           
    List<string> diretorios = new List<string>();            

    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        diretorios.Add(line);
        line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }
    streamReader.Close();


    using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
    {
        ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);

        for (int i = 0; i <= diretorios.Count-1; i++)
        {
            if (diretorios[i].Contains("."))
            {

                string pathRemota = urlFTP + diretorios[i].ToString();
                string pathLocal = Path.Combine(urlFTP, diretorios[i].ToString());
                ftpClient.DownloadFile(pathRemota, pathLocal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Retirei de uma pergunta do Stackoverflow em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526536/how-to-transfer-multiple-files-from-ftp-server-to-local-directory-using-c

Comment: bom dia @Julio Borges, vou ver se essa solução atende a minha necessidade. Obrigado

Comment: @DiegoFarias, Ok, esqueci de comentar no código que ele utiliza o código `if (diretorios[i].Contains("."))` para identificar se o que foi listado é um arquivo ou se é um diretório, considerando que os arquivos listados possuam extensão.

Comment: @DiegoFarias, Se a resposta lhe atendeu, aceite a mesma.

Answer (score -2):

ftpClient.DownloadFile(pathRemota, pathLocal);

Eu fui fazer teste de download de vários arquivos, mas deu erro nesta linha dizendo "Não há suporte para o formato do caminho dado."

Poderiam me ajudar?